# Architecture: whether and how to split information flow

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns

I'm planning to add a feature in a program chain and need an advice with rationale on the information flow.

### Setup

```
DB -- binary -- artifact -- parser -- front-end available quantities
```

I cannot radically change the chain in production, but never the less here is a brief rationale:

- DB stores static data
- Binary takes dynamic (user) input
- Artifact file is used by the user directly and
- Is parsed to get data available to front-end (EPICS PVs)

### Need

**I need to provide a view on the DB to the front-end.** This information is in principle extractable from the artifact as well.

- Do I add a new parser reading the DB?
- Or do I add feature to the current artifact parser?
- Or something else?

Answer (score -1):

My golden rule of programming has always been to segregate and split as much as possible, so components are as decoupled as possible and easy to change.

Comment: atomic functions are ok. the question is where to get the information - at the source or from a product

Comment: The engine shall be generic. Policy and data shall be in the closest component to the user.